# Alphanumeric movement to Numeric

Tags: cobol, mainframe, alphanumeric

Alphanumeric movement to Numeric variable caused unexpected results. Here is the code fyr:

```
  DATA DIVISION.                                 
  WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                       
  01  WS-VAR-STR       PIC X(3) VALUE SPACES.                
  01  WS-VAR-NUM       PIC 9(3) VALUE ZEROES. 
  PROCEDURE DIVISION.                            
      MOVE '1'         TO WS-VAR-STR                  
      MOVE WS-VAR-STR  TO WS-VAR-NUM
      DISPLAY 'STRING > ' WS-VAR-STR '< MOVED > ' WS-VAR-NUM '<'

      IF WS-VAR-NUM >= 40 AND <= 59
         DISPLAY 'INSIDE IF >' WS-VAR-NUM
      ELSE 
         DISPLAY 'INSIDE ELSE >' WS-VAR-NUM
      END-IF
      GOBACK                                     
      .  

    OUTPUT:
    STRING > 1  < MOVED > 1 0<
    INSIDE ELSE >1 O
```

The result is bizzare and want to figure why '1' is moved as '1 0' into numeric variable and interestingly there was NO issue in conditioning it as well. Do share your views. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: I would check if this is not a DISPLAY bug (or feature). Try to write a `IF WS-VAR-NUM EQUAL 1 THEN ...` to check the real content.

Comment: Try MOVE '001' to WS-VAR-STR. Move '1' to WS-VAR-STR moves '1  '. Move does not do type conversion.

Comment: @tony See for example this http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=705710

Comment: @belisarius The convert sub program in the link you provided is how we did it. It removes non-numeric characters, right justifies the numeric characters and zero pads the field. This result can then be moved to the numeric field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have done an illegal `MOVE`. Moving alphanumeric to numeric fields is valid
provided that the content of the alphanumeric field contains only numeric characters.
This [reference](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/IGY3LR31/6.2.24.3?SHELF=&DT=20060329140556&CASE=)
summarizes valid/invalid moves.

What were you expecting as a result?

Moves of alphanumeric fields into numeric ones are done without
'conversion'. Basically you just dropped a one digit followed by two spaces into a numeric field. the '1' was ok, the two spaces
were not. The last two bytes of `WS-VAR-NUM` contain spaces.

But wait... why is the last character a zero? The answer to this is a bit more complicated.
Items declared as `PIC 9` something are represented in Zoned Decimal.
Each digit of a zoned decimal number is represented by a single byte. 
The 4 high-order bits of each byte are zone bits; the 4 high-order bits of the low-order byte represent 
the sign of the item. The 4 low-order bits of each byte contain the value of the digit. The key here
is where the sign is stored. It is in the high order bits of the last byte. Your declaration did not
include a sign so the `MOVE` statement blows away the sign bits and replaces them with default
numeric high order bits (remember the only valid characters to MOVE are digits - so this
patch process should always yield a valid result). The high order bits of an unsigned zoned decimal
digit are always HEX F. What are the low order bits of the last byte? A space has an ebcdic HEX value of 40. A zero is HEX F0. Since the MOVE statement "fixes" the sign automatically, you end up with HEX F0 in the low order digit, which happens to be, you guessed it, zero. None of the other 'digits' contain sign bits so they are left as
they were.

Finally, a `DISPLAY` statement converts zoned decimal fields into their equivalent character representation
for presentation: Net result is: '1 0'.

**BTW** The above discussion is how it works out on an IBM z/OS platform - other character sets (eg. ASCII) and/or other platforms may yield different results, not because IBM is doing the wrong thing, but because the program is doing an illegal `MOVE` and the results are essentially undefined.

Comment: Thanks for such a patient and crystal clear explanation, though its evident that I happened to do an illegal move. Also thanks for understanding my intention to find out the reason for result after such movement. Did you refer something to understand this, if so, please share those valuable stuff... that's indeed worthy!